# Bourne Shell For i in (seq)

Tags: shell, scripting, loops, sh

I want to write a loop in Bourne shell which iterates a specific set of numbers. Normally I would use `seq`:

```
for i in `seq 1 10 15 20`
   #do stuff
loop
```

But seemingly on this Solaris box `seq` does not exist. Can anyone help by providing another solution to iterating a list of numbers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try

```
for i in 1 10 15 20
do
   echo "do something with $i"
done
```

else if you have recent Solaris, there is bash 3 at least. for example this give range from 1 to 10 and 15 to 20

```
for i in {1..10} {15..20}
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

OR use tool like nawk

```
for i in `nawk 'BEGIN{ for(i=1;i<=10;i++) print i}'`
do
  echo $i
done
```

OR even the while loop

```
while [ "$s" -lt 10 ]; do s=`echo $s+1|bc`; echo $s; done
```

Comment: You might want to use `expr $s + 1` instead of `echo $s+1|bc`. The `expr` utility is meant for this sort of thing. Of course with `ksh` or `bash` you can just use shell arithmetic.

Comment: and so is bc. not to mention bc does a lot more than expr. thks for the reminder anyway.

Comment: Why do people prefer the ambiguity of bc to the precision of dc?  Am I really that old?

Comment: @ghostdog74 - ;-) - Perhaps William Pursell is referring to the fact that `bc` uses an actual language so it can say more things than `dc` which is merely an RPN calculator -- combined with Godel's conclusion about languages that if you can say _enough_, you can say ambiguous things. ;-) -- Or maybe he just doesn't like using parenthesis in `bc`. ;-) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate `seq` with `dc`:

For instance:

```
seq 0 5 120
```

is rewritten as:

```
dc -e '0 5 120  1+stsisb[pli+dlt>a]salblax'
```

Comment: +1 for creativity,this-> nawk 'BEGIN{  for(i=0;i<=120;i+=5 )print i }'  does the same and more readable

Comment: I tried to use basic tools, since OP mentions bourne shell. But I didn't think of `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation using `bc`:

```
for i in $(echo "for (i=0;i<=3;i++) i"|bc); do echo "$i"; done
```

For the Bourne shell, you'll probably have to use backticks, but avoid them if you can:

```
for i in `echo "for (i=0;i<=3;i++) i"|bc`; do echo "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 1 10); do
        echo $i
done
```

Comment: He said in the question that seq isn't installed, and is asking for an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

I find that this works, albeit ugly as sin:

```
for i in `echo X \n Y \n Z ` ...
```

Answer (score -4):

```
for i in `seq 1 5 20`; do echo $i; done
```

Result:

```
5
10
15
20
```

$ man seq

```
SEQ(1)                           User Commands                          SEQ(1)

NAME
       seq - print a sequence of numbers

SYNOPSIS
       seq [OPTION]... LAST
       seq [OPTION]... FIRST LAST
       seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
```

Comment: He says in the question that `seq` isn't installed, and is asking for an alternative method.