# countdown in shell without seq or jot

Tags: shell, countdown

I'm trying to make a countdown timer script that takes a number of seconds as `$1`, then counts down to zero, showing the current remaining seconds as it goes.

The catch is, I'm doing this on an embedded box that doesn't have `seq` or `jot`, which are the two tools I know can generate my list of numbers.

Here's the script as I have it working on a normal (non-embedded) system:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in $(/usr/bin/jot ${1:-10} ${1:-10} 1); do
    printf "\r%s " "$i"
    sleep 1
done

echo ""
```

This works in FreeBSD.  If I'm on a Linux box, I can replace the `for` line with:

```
for i in $(/usr/bin/seq ${1:-10} -1 1); do
```

for the same effect.

But what do I do if I have no `jot` OR `seq`?

Comment: What shell are you using?  Not bash, I assume?

Comment: I assume so too.  I don't have a `/bin/bash`, and I know I can't use things like bash parameter expansion. It's a pretty limited system - it doesn't identify itself when I log in, and it has no `uname`. So sorry, let's just assume Bourne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your shell was bash, you could count down from a fixed number with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in {10..1}; do
  printf "\r%s " $n
  sleep 1
done
```

But that won't work for you, because bash won't handle things like `{${1:-10}..1}`, and you've specified you want a command line option.
Of course, you've also said you're not using bash, so we'll assume a simpler shell.

If you have `awk`, you can use that to count.

```
#!/bin/sh

for n in $(awk -v m="${1:-10}" 'BEGIN{for(;m;m--){print m}}'); do
  printf "\r%s " $n
  sleep 1
done
printf "\r \r"  # clean up
```

If you don't have awk, you should be able to do it in pure shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

n=${1:-10}

while [ $n -gt 0 ]; do
  printf "\r%s " $n
  sleep 1
  n=$((n-1))
done
printf "\r \r"  # clean up
```

I think the pure-shell version is probably simple enough that it should be preferred over the awk solution.

Of course, as Mark Reed pointed out in comments, if your system doesn't include a `printf`, then you'll need to perform some ugly `echo` magic that will depend on your OS or shell... and if your shell doesn't support `$((..))`, you can replace that line with `n=$(expr $n - 1)`.  If you want to add error handling in case a non-numeric `$1` is provided, that wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Depending on the shell, might not have arithmetic expressions `$((...))`

Comment: See the notes on my answer about `${1:-10}` and `printf`.  Also, note that `$((...))` is a POSIXism; the embedded shell might not have it.  If it does, that implies that it has integer arithmetic, which means you can also use `while (( n > 0 )); do`.  Also, `let n-=1` or `(( n-=1 ))` may be more efficient as they avoid the string conversion done by `$((..))`

Comment: True and true.  Since we don't know what the actual system is, we're all guessing as to what it supports.  We don't know if this system includes `expr`.  If it doesn't include `seq` then it could be BSD-based, or it could be Linux+BusyBox.  Or it could be something else entirely, or just very old.  Between the bunch of us, Graham probably has enough to answer his question.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with "vanilla" Bourne shell is that there's no such thing; the behavior depends on the particular implementation.  Most modern `/bin/sh`es have POSIX features, but differ in the details. I have a habit of falling back to really ancient Bourne features when I go into "sh-compatibility" mode, which was helpful 30 years ago but is usually overboard on modern systems, even embedded ones. :)

Anyway, here's a generic countdown loop that works even in very old shells, yet still works fine in modern bash/dash/ksh/zsh/etc.  It does require the `expr` command, which is a pretty safe requirement.

```
i=10
while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do
  ...
  i=`expr $i - 1`
done
```

So if your embedded system has `printf`, here's your script, with the same "default to 10 if no argument specified" behavior:

```
#!/bin/sh
n=$1
i=${n-10}
while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do
  printf '\r%s ' "$i"
  i=`expr $i - 1`
  sleep 1
done
```

(The first two lines can probably be replaced with just `i=${1-10}`, but some - again, ancient - shells didn't like applying special parameter expansions to numeric parameters.)

If the system *doesn't* have `printf`, then it becomes problematic; with only the shell's built-in `echo` (or no builtin and some randomly selected implementation of `/bin/echo`), there's no guaranteed way to do either of those things (echo a special character or prevent the newline).  You might be able to use `\r` or `\015` to get the carriage return.  You might need `-e` to get the shell to recognize those (but that might just wind up echoing a literal `-e`). Putting a literal carriage return inside the script will probably work but makes maintaining the script a pain.

Similarly, `-n` might squash the newline, but might just echo a literal `-n`.  The earliest way to squash newlines with `echo` used the special sequence `\c` where the newline would naturally go; this still works with some versions of `/bin/echo` (including the one on Mac OS X) or in conjunction with bash's builtin echo's `-e` option.

So what seems to be the simplest part of the script might be the part that makes you reach for `awk`.

Comment: This system does let me use `${1:-10}`, or I wouldn't have included that in my question. Thanks for the warning though, I'll keep it in mind if I need to create ultra-portable scripts in the future. :) And I do have `printf`.

Comment: Also, your `echo` line doesn't work for me.  If I `i=10; echo '\015'$i'\c'`, I get `\01510\c`.

Comment: @Graham - we don't know what system you have.  It's rude to downvote everyone's answers just because they happen not to work on it, especially when I said right in the answer that the echo might not work.  
`echo ... \c` is how you do no-newlines on some systems (it even still works with `/bin/echo` on OS X).  The octal carriage return was a swing in the dark, but it seemed more likely to work than '\r'.  If you have a way to get a literal CR into the script, that might be best.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, you did suggest experimenting with echo. I didn't realize that `\015` was a carriage return, and I still don't know what `\c` is. I really think you could have explained this a lot more clearly.  I can't remove the downvote unless your answer changes. Perhaps you could put this stuff in your answer?  It's bizarre that the only answer I got that *worked* for me, somebody else downvoted.

Comment: @Graham - fair enough.  Edited for clarification.

Comment: Great turnaround, that's a much better explanation and expansion.  Changed to +1.  I'm leaving the checkmark on the other answer though, because that's the one that actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bash, this is what you want:

```
for i in {1..10}
```

Or no bash? How about the stuff from this post? [Bourne Shell For i in (seq)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102364/bourne-shell-for-i-in-seq)

> try
>
> ```
> for i in 1 10 15 20
> do
>    echo "do something with $i"
> done
> ```
>
> else if you have recent Solaris, there is bash 3 at least. for example
>   this give range from 1 to 10 and 15 to 20
>
> ```
> for i in {1..10} {15..20}
> do
>   echo "$i"
> done
> ```
>
> OR use tool like nawk
>
> ```
> for i in `nawk 'BEGIN{ for(i=1;i<=10;i++) print i}'`
> do
>   echo $i
> done
> ```
>
> OR even the while loop
>
> ```
> while [ "$s" -lt 10 ]; do s=`echo $s+1|bc`; echo $s; done
> ```

Comment: I don't have `nawk` or `bc`, but I guess any `awk` will do. Your other suggestions don't work for me at all, and I don't see how they apply to my question.

Comment: @Graham They apply to your question because they are different ways to loop through a set of numbers. You didn't specify that you didn't have nawk or bc or bash; your question asks about counting in shell "without seq or jot". It's very rude to downvote people for not reading your mind; we are trying to be helpful despite your very vague requirements.

Comment: None of your solutions mention how to get a command line option (`$1`) into a countdown. The second solution suggests bash-style ranges, when I was clear that I don't have bash. Your `nawk` solution counts up (not down), but doesn't say how to get `$1` into the script. It seems to me that you came up with a bunch of script segments that are semi-related to the part of my script that I'm *not* having a problem with, and you provided nothing that actually answers it. Sorry, but that warrants a downvote.

Comment: @Graham I'm sorry, but are you saying that your question was about how to get a command line option into the countdown? Because it reads as a question about generating sequences of numbers using tools other than seq and jot. Your examples, don't bother with `$1`, and neither does the answer you accepted. So I don't really understand what you're getting at with your sudden interest in `$1`. And yes, the example I put counts up, because it's a quote from the post I linked you to, which is a very similar question to yours. You also hadn't mentioned not having bash until after my initial post.

Comment: My original question didn't mention bash at all - the subject says "shell", my example code uses /bin/sh, and there's no bash tag. So there's no reason to assume bash. Then when clarification was asked in comments, I provided it. The subject also says "countdown", which is a hint to the direction the numbers should go. The answer I accepted *does* use `${1:-10}`, which is what I used in my example.

Comment: So you applied a punitive downvote to my question because you assumed things incorrectly, then answered your misinterpretation instead of my question?  That's mature.  You DO realize, don't you, that **`${1:-10}` is a reference to `$1`**?  It's in my question, it's in ghoti's answer, but it's not in your answer.  The reason I made it a requirement is specifically because the counting notation you suggested, the `{1..10}` thing, DOES NOT WORK, even in the shell I'm not using, when you try to use variables as part of the range.

Comment: We obviously disagree. This kind of arguing on the internet doesn't do anybody any good, though, so please move on and leave me alone.